# how to calculate unknown probabilities in the bayesian network

Tags: bayesian-network

I am working on a bayesian network problem. I read from one of the website the following network.

[image]

My problem :

"as soon as the cold water becomes low, you have at least a 94% chance of a high temperature alarm, regardless of whether or not a side reaction occurs".

How can he able to infer that?

Furthermore , "Conversely, the presence of a side reaction here only creates a 90% chance of alarm trigger".

Again , how he can infer that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These quantities cannot be computed without knowing the missing entries of the conditional probability tables.